# Is it possible to do block-comments in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, shortcut, comments

In [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter), you can toggle/comment a block of selected code with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, but this doesn't work in Google Colaboratory notebooks. Is there a way to comment out several lines of Python code easily in a Colaboratory notebook?

I've looked in the documentation, but I came up short.

Comment: A related question is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417825/migrate-my-question-will-i-get-the-reputation-back).

Comment: Time to get a macro keyboard!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the default Colab keyboard shortcuts, you can block comment text using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

If this does not work for you, check *Tools->Keyboard Shortcuts* and search for "Comment Current Line" to see what the shortcut is within your current settings.

Comment: So strange, I could swear I tried this out on Colab and it didn't work for me. Works now though. Thanks.

Comment: If you're in Mac you need to push the Command key as well.

Comment: It is still not working for me. What do you mean by push the Command key?

Comment: @abcd thanks! I can confirm the working shortcut on mac os is `Ctrl+Cmd+/`

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp! For me (in macOS Big Sur 11.4) it works to say **⌘ /** (that is, just  cmd+/, no ctrl required).

Comment: I'm on French keyboard  you have to use ```CTRL+SHIFT+/```

Answer (score 9):

You can select the lines of code and press (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>) to comment or uncomment your selected lines of code.

You can also use triple single quotes (`'''`) at the start and end of the code block you are interested to comment out.

''' ...Your commented code... '''

Comment: I think your second solution is not correct. the three quotes it is for multiline string, not for comment. look this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/C4M-UofT/C4M-UofT.github.io/blob/master/notebooks/strings.ipynb#scrollTo=9Z2LNamTtG4W)

Answer (score 2):

If you are a Mac user, you can use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> for commenting out, and if you want to uncomment again, select the lines and then <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac users who don't have an American keyboard like me: it seems like Colab thinks you are using an American keyboard for shortcuts, and so to make the '/' character you have to press the second button to the right of the 'm'. I'll leave an image to explain.

My keyboard looks like this:

[image: My layout]

As I said, I have to press the <kbd>.</kbd> key to make '/' as if I were using an American keyboard.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the ***next*** key, with "_"/"-" (underscore/dash)? [United States keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#Windows_keyboards)

Answer (score 1):

if you come here with an Italian keyboard you should press:
`command` + `control` + `.`

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users:

- first select the lines that you want to comment
- second push these buttons: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Especially in the Italian keyboard it would be: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> (because the "/" character is combined with button "7")

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I need to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd>.

Which technically is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

(I use an [AZERTYUIOP keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY).)

Answer (score 0):

in my case on mac is : ctr + cmd + -

Answer (score -1):

When using Mac the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

Note that depending on your layout, <kbd>/</kbd> cannot be directly addressed *and its combination is different when combined with <kbd>⌘</kbd>*. For example, on a German keyboard <kbd>/</kbd> is <kbd>[Shift]</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> but the combination <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[Shift]</kbd>+<kbd>ß</kbd>.

When you are unsure about which combination is correct, use [the inbuilt keyboard viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/mac) which provides a live view of the meaning of keys while selecting modifiers.

Keyboard Viewer: default keyboard mapping

[image]

Keyboard Viewer: modifier keys keyboard mapping

[image]