# How to do block-comments in Google Colab on a Mac with a non-American keyboard?

Tags: macos, google-colaboratory, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to do block-comments in Colab using a Mac laptop ([Big Sur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur)), so I had a look here:

*[Is it possible to do block-comments in Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59536088/is-it-possible-to-do-block-comments-in-google-colab/59567365#59567365)*

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> does not work for me, so I follow [jakevdp's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59536088/is-it-possible-to-do-block-comments-in-google-colab/59567365#59567365):

> If this does not work for you, check Tools->Keyboard Shortcuts and search for "Comment Current Line" to see what the shortcut is within your current settings.

Here's the output:

[image]

This leads to several problems:

1. The shortcut I need is one of the very few that can't be customized.
2. On my non-American keyboard, I need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+`7`, to get `/`
3. On the Mac, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + `7` is bound to the Help menu: *[How to use the macOS Help menu](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/use-the-macos-help-menu/)*

To summarize, every time I try to comment a block of code, the *Help* menu opens instead. Is there any workaround for this?

PS: I tried all the other answers to *[Is it possible to do block-comments in Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59536088/is-it-possible-to-do-block-comments-in-google-colab)*, and they didn't work.

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417825/migrate-my-question-will-i-get-the-reputation-back).

Comment: "non-American keyboard" What keyboard *do* you have? Why not change the keyboard layout? Note that ⌘+Shift+7 doesn't open the help menue on my Mac (it's the shortcut for "show status bar" in Safari) so does not seem to be set in stone either.

Comment: It could be [a Spanish](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/keyboard-print-skips-keys/75525#75525) or Danish keyboard layout.

Comment: FWIW, using `⌘` *changes* the meaning of some special keys. On my German keyboard, `/` is `Shift+7` but `⌘+/` is ``⌘+Shift+ß`.

Comment: A few Suggs: 1- Switch Keyboard Layout - do your Shortcut - switch back... // 2- Remap one Key you don't use to `/` using some Remap Keyboard Manager/Utility... // 3- Plug in some USB US/International Keyboard...

Comment: ... // 4- Use the Stack Overflow USB Keyboard '[The Key v2.0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411816/3799241) with 4 Keys and remap the programmable Key to `/`... :idea:

Comment: @PeterMortensen you got it :-)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi changing the keyboard layout just to use Colab is a no-no - it will mess up the rest of my workflow. I like my current keyboard layout :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution. If the standard solution <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> doesn't work for you (like it didn't for me)....just use the <kbd>/</kbd> from the numeric keypad!

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + numeric keypad <kbd>7</kbd> worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

for Italian keyboard on Mac OS the shortcut is:
⌘ + Ctrl + .